# I get this error after calling tabulate TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Tags: python

```
from tabulate import tabulate

mydata= [('29.16', '30.10', '1', '7')
         ('20.83', '17.60', '2', '5')
         ('12.50', '12.49', '3', '3')
         ('8.33', '9.69', '4', '2')
         ('8.33', '7.92', '5', '2')
         ('8.33', '6.69', '6', '2')
         ('0', '5.80', '7', '0')
         ('8.33', '5.12', '8', '2')
         ('4.17', '4.58', '9', '1')]

header= [('Actual Value', 'Predicted value', 'Leading Digit value', 'Count')
         ]

print(tabulate(mydata, headers=header))
```

Comment: You're missing commas after each line in `mydata`.

Comment: You are missing commas at the end of each row.

Comment: Because there is no comma, python takes that second opening parenthesis to mean that this is a function call. So it tries to call `('29.16', '30.10', '1', '7')` with parameter list `('20.83', '17.60', '2', '5')`. Of course, its a tuple not a function and thus the error.

Comment: Please provide the entire error output. What do you understand from that error?

Answer (score 1):

There is some error with your typing. You are missing `commas`(`,`) at `mydata`, referred above at comment. To solve the solution, you should change

```
mydata= [('29.16', '30.10', '1', '7')
         ('20.83', '17.60', '2', '5')
         ('12.50', '12.49', '3', '3')
         ('8.33', '9.69', '4', '2')
         ('8.33', '7.92', '5', '2')
         ('8.33', '6.69', '6', '2')
         ('0', '5.80', '7', '0')
         ('8.33', '5.12', '8', '2')
         ('4.17', '4.58', '9', '1')]
```

To

```
mydata= [('29.16', '30.10', '1', '7'),
         ('20.83', '17.60', '2', '5'),
         ('12.50', '12.49', '3', '3'),
         ('8.33', '9.69', '4', '2'),
         ('8.33', '7.92', '5', '2'),
         ('8.33', '6.69', '6', '2'),
         ('0', '5.80', '7', '0'),
         ('8.33', '5.12', '8', '2'),
         ('4.17', '4.58', '9', '1')]
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you should only add a comma between each tuple in your mydata definition.